# hibernate one to many relationship, child table foriegn key table setting 0 value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Hi All creating one to many realtionship.
I have 2 table one is Emp and other is Project.
One Emp can have many Project.
These are my bean class.

```
 public class Emp {

    public List<Project> getProjectList() {
        return projectList;
    }

    public void setProjectList(List<Project> projectList) {
        this.projectList = projectList;
    }

    @Generated(value = { "id" })
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String  city;

    @OneToMany( cascade=CascadeType.ALL , fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="emp",orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Project> projectList=new ArrayList<Project>();


    public void addProject(Project project) {
        this.projectList.add(project);
        if (project.getEmp() != this) {
            project.setEmployer(this);
        }
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

}
```

This is the project class

```
 @Entity
        public class Project {




        @Generated(value = { "id" })
        @Id
        private int id;

        @Column(name="name")
        private String name;

        @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="empid", nullable=false)
        private Emp emp;


        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }


        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }


        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }


        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


        public Emp getEmp() {
            return emp;
        }


        public void setEmp(Emp emp) {
            this.emp = emp;
        }


        public void setEmployer(Emp emp2) {
             this.emp = emp2;
                if (!emp2.getProjectList().contains(this)) { // warning this may cause performance issues if you have a large data set since this operation is O(n)
                    emp.getProjectList().add(this);
                }


        }

    }
```

This is my code to save the parent and child

```
public class MainTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(org.hibernate.model.Emp.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(org.hibernate.model.Project.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(org.hibernate.model.Stu.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(org.hibernate.model.Address.class);



    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "123456789");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();


Session session =   sessionFactory.openSession();
org.hibernate.Transaction transaction =session.beginTransaction();

Emp emp = new Emp();
emp.setCity("nagaland");
emp.setName("divyffa");

Project project1=new Project();
project1.setName("dotedxvc");
emp.addProject(project1);
session.save(emp);
transaction.commit();
session.close();



}


}
```

These is the structure of my table

```
      CREATE TABLE `emp` (

      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `city` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


    CREATE TABLE `project` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `empid` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  KEY `forgn-project_idx` (`empid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Whenever I save my Parent class my child class also get saved but the empid column value is getting saved as 0. Each time it is getting saved as 0.

Please I  Don't know what is the issue and thanks for the help.
I have Search about this issue but not find any result.

Answer (score 1):

It seem to be that  you have set only one side of relationship.
I think some thing like below need here

project1.setEmp(emp);

Comment: Have you seen my pojo.I have add method which added my object on both the side.It synchronize the both object

Comment: sorry my bad..another point to focus is  using a fetch type @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)

Answer (score 0):

I think your FOREIGN KEY column should refer to the parent table means "emp" table PRIMARY KEY column. I have modified child table means "project" structure like-

```
CREATE TABLE `project` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`empid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (empid) REFERENCES emp (id)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In Emp entity class add @OneToMany mapping as-

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="emp")
     private List projectList;

and also in Project entity class modify @ManyToOne mapping as-

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "empid", insertable = true)  
private Emp emp;
```

I guess this will work for you.